# Error while setting up Email Experience Manager Campaign in Sitecore 10.3

Tags: exm

Currently using Sitecore 10.3 version, while setting up Email campaign in Email Experience Manager getting below error message. Our License is configured for EXM Custom SMTP setup.
[image: From Email is not valid getting cross sign]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a new domain as explained in Sitecore documenation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/adding-or-editing-a-domain.html